# Tensorflow argmax along multiple dimensions

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm newbie to `tensorflow` and I'm trying to get the index of the maximum value in a Tensor. Here is the code:

```
def select(input_layer):

    shape = input_layer.get_shape().as_list()

    rel = tf.nn.relu(input_layer)
    print (rel)
    redu = tf.reduce_sum(rel,3)
    print (redu)

    location2 = tf.argmax(redu, 1)
    print (location2)

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
I = tf.random_uniform([32, 3, 3, 5], minval = -541, maxval = 23, dtype = tf.float32)
matI, matO = sess.run([I, select(I, 3)])
print(matI, matO)
```

Here is the output:

```
Tensor("Relu:0", shape=(32, 3, 3, 5), dtype=float32)
Tensor("Sum:0", shape=(32, 3, 3), dtype=float32)
Tensor("ArgMax:0", shape=(32, 3), dtype=int64)
...
```

Because of dimension=1 in the `argmax` function the shape of `Tensor("ArgMax:0") = (32,3)`. Is there any way to get a `argmax` output tensor size = `(32,)` without doing `reshape` before applying the `argmax`?

Comment: What's wrong with a `tf.reshape(redu, [32, -1])`? [`tf.argmax`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/argmax) will only reduce along one axis

Answer (score 2):

You problably don't want an output of size `(32,)` because when you `argmax` along several directions, you usually want to have the coordinates of the max for all the reduced dimensions. In your case, you would want to have an output of size `(32,2)`.

You can do a two-dimensional `argmax` like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

x = np.zeros((10,9,8))
# pick a random position for each batch image that we set to 1
pos = np.stack([np.random.randint(9,size=10), np.random.randint(8,size=10)])

posext = np.concatenate([np.expand_dims([i for i in range(10)], axis=0), pos])
x[tuple(posext)] = 1

a = tf.argmax(tf.reshape(x, [10, -1]), axis=1)
pos2 = tf.stack([a // 8, tf.mod(a, 8)]) # recovered positions, one per batch image

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
# check that the recovered positions are as expected
assert (pos == pos2.eval()).all(), "it did not work"
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but the problem is that I'm using tensorflow version 0.9 and tf.stack does not exist in that version. Do you have an alternative?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have version 0.9 and tensorflow.org has the docs from 0.10 onwards only. If concatenation was present, you could perhaps combine it with `expand_dims` to simulate `stack`.